# Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value In Container View in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I am new to iOS and currently I am working with container view using tutorial **https://kodesnippets.wordpress.com/2015/08/11/container-view-in-ios/**

And I want to add one functionality i.e. in **Second View Controller** I want to add a button and then on click of that button I want to open **Third View Controller** in the same container view that lies under **ViewController.swift**.

Now, problem is that when I click on **Button** in **Second View Controller** then It shows me **fatal exception** that I have mentioned in question.

Code for **Second View Controller** on button's **Touch Up Inside**

```
  @IBAction func send(_ sender: UIButton) {

    container!.segueIdentifierReceivedFromParent("Third")

}
```

Please help if anyone knows.

Comment: you might have re added IBOutlet, Right click on your button see if there are multiple outlsets are present or not.

Comment: Tell me am I right is it possible to do the same @Dev_Tandel

Comment: I do not have any outlset just have one send event i.e. touch up inside @Dev_Tandel

Comment: sorry , i didn't get you @Android Developer

Comment: I mean do using this approach what I am doing.. Is I  will be able to achieve the same that I had explained in my question @Dev_Tandel

Comment: Check for the identifier of segue "Third" They are case sensitive

Comment: you will get nil object when it is not allocated.

Comment: Yes I checked. I wrote "Third" perfectly but my one question is that I have connected the same container view to third view controller @Dev_Tandel

Comment: http://prntscr.com/h32n99 check this scrernshot of my storyboard @Dev_Tandel

Comment: Still getting null pointer exception in it. @Dev_Tandel

Comment: Did you check the code example here? https://github.com/iaaqib/ContainerView

Comment: I think the transition you're trying to do is wrong i.e. going to ThirdViewController from Second.You'll need to switch the controllers using the ViewController and not the SecondViewController.

Comment: container?.segueIdentifierReceivedFromParent("Third") Try this

Comment: I wouldn't rely on this tutorial. In fact, it's not about the container view in iOS, it's about the [containment API](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html). The title is totally misleading. What's more, it shows horrible use case of the custom segues and doesn't say a word about containment API which really powers up this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have pushed a new Storyboard with name Secondary.storyboard, with your requirement added. Give it a try. See the attached image.

https://github.com/iaaqib/ContainerView

[image]

Comment: If I am adding one more button in second view controller and then code in view controller and second view controller it throws me an error i.e. http://prntscr.com/h3tp9h

Comment: Show your code?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3bn04yG6nn7b0x4SnU5ZWJ5eUk/view?usp=sharing         
This is my code. Please check this.

Comment: Can you please tell me why I am not able to go to next view controller. My document is here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3bn04yG6nn7b0x4SnU5ZWJ5eUk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: To be honest this is not how container view is supposed to be used and your question is really hard to understand. Although I gave a pretty good example above. I'm not sure what you're doing wrong now, without seeing your project.

Comment: I can mail you my project. If you want